# Client.Socket.SendText from of a Form that is displayed above of other Form that stays always on top

Tags: forms, sockets, delphi

I'm with difficulties for send text from a *Client.Socket*. The Form that sends the text, is displayed always above of Form that stays always on top, when `FormOnTop` not exists (not is showing), works fine, already when `FormOnTop` exists and Form that will sends the text is displayed above of `FormOntop`, the send fail, and text (message) not even exit of Client.exe of my software.

There are some solution for this?

For better understand, I will leave the code that I using:

***Form that contains Client Socket component***

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  FormSender;

type
 ......

end;

 var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.CS1Read(Sender: TObject; Socket: TCustomWinSocket);
var
  StrCommand: String;
begin

    StrCommand := Socket.ReceiveText;

  if Pos('<|Command_From_Server|>', StrCommand) > 0 then

   begin

     FormSender.PopupMode:= pmExplicit;
     FormSender.PopupParent:= FormOnTop;
     FormSender.Show;

   end;
end;

end.
```

***Form that sends text (FormSender) and appear above of Form that stays always On Top:***

```
unit FormSender;

interface

uses
  Unit1;

type
 ......

end;

 var
  FormSender: TFormSender;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TFormSender.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin

 Form1.CS1.Socket.SendText('<|Hello_Server!|>' + Edit1.Text + '<<|);

end;

end.
```

**Form that stays always on top:**

FormStyle property is: `fsStayOnTop`.

```
   unit FormOnTop;

        interface

        uses
          .......

        type
         ......

        end;

         var
          FormOnTop: TFormOnTop;

        implementation

        {$R *.dfm}

    procedure TFormOnTop.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    begin
    { Position form }
      Top := 0 ;
      Left := 0 ;

      { Go full screen }
      BorderStyle := bsNone ;
      WindowState  := wsmaximized;
      ClientWidth  := Screen.Width ;
      ClientHeight := Screen.Height;
      Refresh;
      SetForegroundWindow(Handle) ;
      SetActiveWindow(Application.Handle);

    end;

    procedure TFormOnTop.CreateParams(var Params: TCreateParams);
    begin
      inherited;
      if (FormStyle = fsStayOnTop) then begin
        Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
        Params.WndParent := GetDesktopWindow;
      end;
    end;

procedure TFormOnTop.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
 SetWindowPos(FormOnTop.handle, HWND_TOPMOST, FormOnTop.Left, FormOnTop.Top, FormOnTop.Width, FormOnTop.Height, 0);
end;


end.
```

Comment: Please clarify: Is `FormMain` (referred to in `Unit1`) yet another form, or is it possibly the `FormOnTop`? You can not have a unit called      ´FormOnTop` and form called the same! You also refer to `FormSender` in the uses of `Unit1`, and to `Unit1` in uses of `FormSender`, thus creating a circular reference. It is hard to take your code seriously after such errors. Does the `FormSender` form popup after message received by Unit1?

Comment: @TomBrunberg, "`FormSender`" is a alias of example. This "`FormSender`" is the Form that will send text to my "Server.exe", this "`FormSender`" is open over "`FormAlwaysOnTop`", but the send fail when "`FormOnTop`" is showing. Already when open only "`FormSender`" without "`FormOnTop`" is running, works perfectly. You understood now?

Comment: Which Delphi version? Do you have the same problem if you outcomment the `SetActiveWindow()` in `TFormOnTop.FormCreate()`? You did not answer my question regarding `FormMain` referred to in Unit1 (`FormSender.PopupParent:= FormMain;`)

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I edited my code above in this point. I'm using Delphi XE5, and "hiding" `SetActiveWindow()` don't made diference, the trouble still exists.

Comment: I have now installed the socket components, created a server and a client similar to your, but I can not reproduce your problem. Sorry.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, I solved my trouble, thank you very much friend!